# Dockerize .NET CORE web App with dependent class library

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose

Using docker (compose) in a C# 6.0 API project with class library dependecies throws error, that the dependent library was not found and [this article](https://imranarshad.com/dockerize-net-core-web-app-with-dependent-class-library/) says I should move Docker file to solution level. But I have another API project in the solution (using the same class library) that has own Docker file. So I cannot move the dockerfile to solution level.

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your build context to the directory above your current directory, without moving your Dockerfile.

You need to modify the Dockerfile so paths etc. in it work relative to the parent directory.

Then build the image using the same command you've used until now, but change the context from `.` to `..`. If your build command was

```
docker build -t my-image .
```

you should now use

```
docker build -t my-image ..
```

By moving your build context up a level, you should be able to access the project with the dependent class library and include that in your image.